# Getting XML format for MS Health Vault

Tags: .net, healthvault

I need to figure out the way to get all the records in a one file from MS Health Vault which include all medication, allergy, problem, conditions, insurance and so on. So in other words I need to find out the way to get one XML file (i.e. CCR) using MS HealthValut object model or object methods with all the data in it. Currently while entering a patientID and recordID I am getting only one attribute.

It would be great if someone could help me out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want similar to below request.
This request downloads the Weight & Heart Rate data from the server.

```
"<info><group max=\"100\"><filter>" + 
        "<type-id>" +Weight.TYPE + "</type-id>" +
        "<type-id>" +HeartRate.TYPE + "</type-id>" +
        "</filter><format><section>core</section>" +
        "<xml/></format></group></info>";
```

Where Weight.TYPE = "3d34d87e-7fc1-4153-800f-f56592cb0d17"; &
HeartRate.TYPE = "b81eb4a6-6eac-4292-ae93-3872d6870994";

You can add more TYPEs as you require.
Once the response arrives, you can dump it to file (You need to convert from InputStream to File)

Hope this helps